# Efecto subrayado en hover con enlace

Tags: jquery, html, html5, css, css3

Necesito recortar la anchura horizontal de un border-bottom para mostrar el efecto siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("p").hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('over');
});
```

```css
.over {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.over:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

p {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p >Parrafo 1</p>
<p >Parrafo 2</p>
<p >Parrafo 4</p>
<p >Parrafo 5</p>
```

Espero poder ayudarte, saludos

Comment: Excelente colega, tu respuesta fue absoluta y efectiva. Muchisimas gracias! Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes agregar un pseudo elemento a la etiqueta, más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502675/css-underline-less-than-width-of-headline) (enlace en inglés)

```
h1 {
font-weight: 300;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

CSS

```
h1:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; //ANCHO DE LA UNDERLINE
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias colega, tu respuesta estuve super cerca. Un abrazo